# Find all natural numbers $n$ such that $n+1$ divides $3n+11$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Following the example of my teacher:

> Find all natural numbers $n$ such that $n-2$ divides $n+5$.
>
> $$n+5 = n-2+7$$
>
> As $n-2|n-2$, $n-2$ will divide $n+5$ if and only if $n-2|7$. Yet, $7$ has the divisors $-7$, $-1$, $1$, $7$ hence the equations:
>
> - $n-2=-7 \Leftrightarrow n = -5 $
> - $n-2=-1 \Leftrightarrow n = 1 $
> - $n-2=7 \Leftrightarrow n = 3 $
> - $n-2=-1 \Leftrightarrow n = 9 $
>
> So $S = \{ 1, 3, 9 \}$

I decompose $n+1$ the exact same way:

$$n+1 = 3n+11 - 2(n+5)$$

But I'd get stuck as $2(n+5)$ since only $-2$, $-1$, $1$ and $2$ are divisors, which don't satisify the equation as I'd hoped:

- $3n+11 = -2 \Leftrightarrow n =\frac{-13}{3}$
- $3n+11 = -1 \Leftrightarrow n = -4$
- $3n+11 = 1 \Leftrightarrow n =\frac{-10}{3}$
- $3n+11 = 1 \Leftrightarrow n = -3$

Any clues?

Comment: What has $n+5$ to do with this?

Comment: It's more intuitive if you use congruences - see my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$n+1$ certainly divides $3n+3$. If it divides $3n+11$, it must also
divide $(3n+11)-(3n+3)$.

Answer (score 2):

You can use polynomial long division, which is useful if you have a more complex expression:

$$
\require{enclose}
\begin{array}{rll}
    3 && \\[-3pt]
   n+1 \enclose{longdiv}{\ 3n+11}\kern-.2ex \\[-3pt]
      \ \ - \underline{\ (3n+3)} &&  \\[-3pt]
      8 &&  \\[-3pt]
  \end{array}
$$

Therefore $\frac{3n+11}{n+1} = 3 + \frac{8}{n+1}$. Can you continue?

Comment: +1 for being a much clearer explanation than the teachers **and** for being the first time I've seen long division in LaTeX.

Comment: Thanks man! I personally learnt it this way, but I prefer synthetic division which is probably out of reach for the OP here. The MathJax was copied from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22867785/way-to-show-long-division-symbol-in-mathjax).

Comment: I just taught synthetic division to my AP Calc students this week.  It isn't so bad as long as you can look at it alongside polynomial long division and understand that the same numbers show up in both diagrams and why the subtraction got to change to addition.

Answer (score 1):

Set $n+1=m$

$3n+11=3(m-1)+11=3m+8\equiv8\pmod m$

Answer (score 1):

When the example has
$$  n + 5 = n-2 + 7  $$
it might have been more clearly written 
$$  n + 5 = 1\cdot(n-2) + 7  $$
to highlight the quotient, $1$, and remainder, $7$, of the division $\frac{n+5}{n-2}$.

For your problem, 
$$  3n + 11 = 3 \cdot (n+1) + 8  \text{.}  $$
That is, the quotient is $3$ and the remainder is $8$.  So you want to inspect the choices of $n$ such that $(n+1) \mid 8$.

Answer (score 1):

$\!\! \bmod n\!+\!1\!:\,\ \color{#c00}{n\equiv -1}\,\Rightarrow\, 3\,\color{#c00}n+11\equiv 3(\color{#c00}{-1})+11\equiv 8\ $ by [Congruence Sum & Product Rules](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/879262/242) $\ \ \ \ \ $